# numpy.argmax() on multi-dim data does not return an ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

The documentation of `numpy.argmax` states that it returns the index position of the maximum value found in the array and it does so by returning an `ndarray` of `int` with the same shape as the input array:

```
numpy.argmax(a, axis=None, out=None)[source]

Returns the indices of the maximum values along an axis.
Parameters: 
a : array_like
    Input array.

axis : int, optional
    By default, the index is into the flattened array, otherwise along the specified axis.

out : array, optional
    If provided, the result will be inserted into this array. It should be of the appropriate shape and dtype.

Returns:    
index_array : ndarray of ints

    Array of indices into the array. It has the same shape as a.shape with the dimension along axis removed.
```

Why then does the command return for a 2-dim array a single `int`?

```
a = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)

print np.argmax(a)
5
```

It seems to me the reshape acts as a new view and the argmax command still uses the underlying 1-dim array. I tried copying the array into an initialized 2-dim array with the same end result.

This is Python 2.7.12 but since they have it in the documentation I believe this is the expected behavior. Am I missing anything? How can I get the ndarray returned?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation you quoted:

> **By default, the index is into the flattened array**

It's providing the integer such that `a.flat[np.argmax(a)] == np.max(a)`. If you want to convert this into an index tuple, you can use the [`np.unravel_index`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html#numpy.unravel_index) function linked in the "See also" section.

The part about "the same shape as *a.shape* with the dimension along *axis* removed" applies if you actually provide an `axis` argument. Also, note the "with the dimension along *axis* removed" part; even if you specify `axis`, it won't return an array of the same shape as the input like you were expecting.